# Exiting in node.js after recursive function is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, callback

I try to rewire my brain for async coding and I still I still seem to fail. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do it properly in this case. Let me give an example:

```js
var nconf = require('nconf');

 nconf.argv()
 .env();

 function runme(callback){
   var nummessages = nconf.get('SMS_MESSAGES');
   decodemessage(0, nummessages);
   callback();
 }

 function decodemessage(i, nummessages) {
  if( i < nummessages ) {
    var message = 'SMS_'+(i+1)+'_TEXT';
    var number = 'SMS_'+(i+1)+'_NUMBER';
    console.log('number: '+number);
    console.log('message: '+message);
    console.log('message text: '+ nconf.get(message));
    console.log('message number: '+ nconf.get(number));
    decodemessage(i+1);
  }
} 

runme(function(){
  process.exit(0);
});
```

This gets called by gammu-smsd which receives SMS messages and puts them into ENV vars and launches a script. This works fine as long as I run it on my own, return code seems to work as well. When I run it from gammu-smsd it fails and it looks like decodemessage is never executed. Some debug output shows that I do go into runme().

My guess is that the callback in runme() gets executed before the recursive decodemessage() call is done. Am I right and if so can someone explain how I can do that properly?

If you want to test run it like this:

```
node server.js --SMS_MESSAGES 2 --SMS_1_TEXT blabliblo --SMS_1_NUMBER=47796546546 --SMS_2_TEXT Iammessagetwo --SMS_2_NUMBER 12345678
```

Thanks

Comment: No, not if the recursive `decodemessage` is synchronous. Actually, where is the async part that requires the use of a callback at all?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, all I want to assure with the callback is that when everything is done and the recursion returns my script exists with 0.

Comment: Javascript execution is single-threaded. So if you don't have any asynchronous stuff, you should just use a normal for-loop and place the `process.exit(0)` statement right after it. If you have async stuff, show it to us (there is none in your example code)!

Comment: ok I see what you mean. I now did a for-loop edition and while it works in the test it does not from gammu-sms, again it doesn't enter the loop. So I have some weird problem I have to figure out, will report back. I will post data via request later so this will be async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to pass on the `nummessages` in your recursive call:

```
decodemessage(i+1, nummessages);
```

That's why I personally mostly loop backwards (to zero) when using recursion.

Comment: Tnx that's correct, I had a closure before that's why I forgot to add it. However this does not seem to fix the problem, it still doesn't go into decodemessage when I launch it from gammu-smsd.

Comment: I close this one, I'm pretty sure gammu-smsd does something wrong and the code was correct. Thanks for the hints guys.